# The Div parts goes into one?

Tags: html, css-float, html-lists

i have a problem so much googled and tried to solve it, but i can't.

my problem is so easy to say.
the code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.box_list li
{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 49%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <ul class="box_list">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>USA</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to have this output:

```
1    2
3
USA
```

but unfortunately my code's output is:

```
1   2
3   USA
```

Please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

css add:

```
.clear{
  clear:both;
  display:block;
}
```

html add:

```
<li>2</li><br/>
```

And

```
<div class="clear">USA</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have two different lists. Here's how I would do it.

```
    <ul id="list1"><li>1</li><li>3</li><li>USA</li></ul><ul id="list2"><li>2</li></ul>
```

Now for the CSS.

```
    #list1{ float:left; list-style-type:none; } #list2{ float:left; list-style-type:none; }
```

Comment: Edited my answer to get rid of the List-style-type.

Comment: Thanks Mardin, but the second DIV is not list.. its a simple DIV.

Comment: Ok, I hope it at least helped

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sort of css

```
    .box_list li
    {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        width: 49%;
        background-color:#eee;
    }
    .box_list li:nth-child(odd){
        clear:both;
    }
```